# Retrying an observable using retryWhen()

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, rx-java2

I'm implementing an observable which retries on error after a delay of 5s. I'm using retrofit for networking. The problem i'm facing is that there are a lot of retries when the API returns an error. I want to retry only after 5s but the retry happens at an insane rate(almost three times in a second). Any idea why?

```
userAPI.getUsers()
       .filter { it.users.isNotEmpty() }
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .retryWhen { errors -> errors.flatMap { errors.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) } }
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe({}, {})
```

where `userAPI.getUsers()` returns an observable.

Insane number of API requests:

```
08-13 12:31:31.308 26277-26453/com.app.user.dummy D/OkHttp: --> GET https://userapi.com/foo
08-13 12:31:31.825 26277-26453/com.app.user.dummy D/OkHttp: --> GET https://userapi.com/foo
08-13 12:31:32.370 26277-26453/com.app.user.dummy D/OkHttp: --> GET https://userapi.com/foo
08-13 12:31:32.897 26277-26453/com.app.user.dummy D/OkHttp: --> GET https://userapi.com/foo
08-13 12:31:33.436 26277-26453/com.app.user.dummy D/OkHttp: --> GET https://userapi.com/foo
08-13 12:31:33.952 26277-26453/com.app.user.dummy D/OkHttp: --> GET https://userapi.com/foo
08-13 12:31:34.477 26277-26453/com.app.user.dummy D/OkHttp: --> GET https://userapi.com/foo
08-13 12:31:35.020 26277-26453/com.app.user.dummy D/OkHttp: --> GET https://userapi.com/foo
08-13 12:31:35.609 26277-26453/com.app.user.dummy D/OkHttp: --> GET https://userapi.com/foo
08-13 12:31:36.205 26277-26453/com.app.user.dummy D/OkHttp: --> GET https://userapi.com/foo
```

P.S: i've already gone through the blog post by Dan lew on retryWhen and repeatWhen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look into Dan Lew's blog post again where he actually describes a solution for your use case under **Uses** title.

`source.retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> Observable.timer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))`

Explanation:

Notice the difference between `Observable.delay` and `Observable.timer` as `Observable.delay`'s documentation states that

> Error notifications from the source Observable are not delayed.

In retryWhen your `errors` Observable is subscribed to immediately (as `Observable.delay` only delays onNext) and then the source errors out again and immediately emits the error, that triggers retryWhen and you enter a recursive loop.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be in your flatmap function lambda i.e.

```
.retryWhen({ errors -> errors.flatMap { errors.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) } })
```

(I'm assuming the lack of brackets is a typo).  The result is that the Observable that gets passed to retryWhen immediately terminates resulting in the "insane" retry rate when you get an error.

Try

```
userAPI.getUsers()
   .filter { it.users.isNotEmpty() }
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
   .retryWhen({ errors -> errors.flatMap { error -> Observable.just(1).delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS) } })
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .subscribe({}, {})
```

Comment: why would this work? "try this" answers are usually not really helpful unless you explain what is different and why

Comment: The original post did not perform the `flatMap()` correctly. Fixing that error in the manner that @JohnWowUs describes should make the problem go away.